# ActionScript 3.0: How to convert JPEG-encoded ByteArray to Bitmap

Tags: actionscript, bitmap, arrays, jpeg

ActionScript 3.0: How to convert JPEG-encoded ByteArray to Bitmap
The JPEGEncoder class can convert the raw bitmapdata into JPEG-encoded ByteArray Object, and I just want to know how to do the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can do it simply using `Loader.loadBytes`:

```
private var loader:Loader = new Loader();

private function convertByteArray(ba:ByteArray):void
{
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    loader.loadBytes(ba);
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{       
    var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(loader.content);
}
```